# code after else not fully working with jquery, javascript. I'm so confused :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I am very new to javascript and jquery. I can't even figure out how to debug and view log files like I can with php :(  So I am hoping someone here will help.

I have this simple code which for the most part works. Its just the if / else

The problem is that if chklogin == 1 as shown below $('#myModal').show(); does what i expect it to do.

However if its not = to 1, $('#myModal').show(); does not work.  I also know I am in the else part of my code because I stuck the alert in there that actually displays the message. Its just the other statements don't work when they do otherwise.

```
   $("[id^='mod_']").click( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = this.href;

      var chklogin = $(this).attr("data-modalchklogin");
      var h2       = $(this).attr("data-modalh2");
      var h3       = "Thanks!";
      var line1    = $(this).attr("data-modaltext1");
      var line2    = $(this).attr("data-modaltext2");


      if ( chklogin == 1 ) {
         $.post("ajaxqueries.php", {"checkloggedin": ''}, function(data) {
            var loggedin = data;
            if ( loggedin == 0 ) {
               $('#myModal').show();
               $('#ModalH2').text(h2);
               $('#ModalH3').text(h3);
               $('#ModalLineOne').html(line1);
               $('#ModalLineTwo').html(line2);
            } else {
               window.location = url;
            }
         });
      } else {
         alert('I am here');
         $('#myModal').show();
         $('#ModalH2').text(h2);
         $('#ModalH3').text(h3);
         $('#ModalLineOne').html(line1);
         $('#ModalLineTwo').html(line2);
      }

   });
```

Thanks for looking !!!

Comment: Is your `<script>` maybe in the `<head>` and `<div id="myModal">` in the `<body>`?

Comment: yes, <script> is in head but function is after $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: *"I can't even figure out how to debug and view log files"* - In most browsers pressing F12 opens the developer tools, which include a "Console" tab that shows error messages. Though I don't see anything wrong with the code after the `alert()` in the `else`.

Comment: Your first .show is in a callback from a post. Is it possible that the .show in your else condition runs before myModal is loaded in the DOM? You mention your function is after document.ready? Can you move it inside the .ready callback?

Answer (score 1):

You should `console.log($('#myModal'));` before `$('#myModal').show();`
and see what it is. Then `console.log('whatever')` after `$('#myModal').show();`.

After that you might know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your code has a node (`< >`) with `id = "myModal"`.
If so, open your browser debug tools (in Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>) and check if any error occurred.